# Mysql Workbench GROUP BY

Tags: mysql, sql, mysql-workbench

I run this query on my MySQL workbench and I have this problem. Do you have any idea?

```
select location, date, total_cases, total_deaths, continent, 
(total_deaths / total_cases)* 100 as DeathPercentage
From mikaeil
GROUP BY date
```

Error is:

> Error Code: 1055. Expression #1 of SELECT list is not in GROUP BY clause and contains nonaggregated column 'mikaeil.mikaeil.location' which is not functionally dependent on columns in GROUP BY clause; this is incompatible with sql_mode=only_full_group_by 0,00072 sec

Comment: You need in all columns values separately, so GROUP BY is not needed. Why you add it? if you need to remove duplicated rows then you'd use DISTINCT.

Comment: You are selecting no group-by column data 
to achieve this setting ```set sql_mode=''``` this will set sql_mode to null

Comment: welcome to stackoverflow mikaeil! if you could provide table structure, sample data, and expected result to work with that would be nice. anyway, have you checked [ask]?

Comment: It's generally recommended to do not use SQL key words like "date" as column name or table name.